# (Cordova 6.5.0 - iOS 4.3.1) Stills on splash screen forever. Xcode console: Resetting plugins due to page load. Finished load of: index.html

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, cordova, splash-screen

I am using Cordova 6.5.0 with iOS 4.3.1 and it doesn't load the application. I stays on splash-screen with a forever load.

At xcode console I get this:

**APP_DID_BECOME_ACTIVE
Resetting plugins due to page load.
Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/A5844174-8E6B-4668-A97E-08D320D64DC7/testing.app/www/index.html**

There are a lot of similar questions, but none helped me.

Comment: Do you have a Content-Security-Policy meta tag? in case you have it, can you post it? Also the config.xml or at least the part where you configure the splash screen

Comment: Have you been able to resolve that ?

Comment: Yes, the problem was a plugin with configurations error.